# To physically exchange money: (um) tauschen, wechseln, konvertieren, umrechnen

Tags: synonym

Gibt es Bedeutungsunterschiede zwischen "wechseln", "umtauschen" und "konvertieren", wenn sie die Bedeutung von "to exchange money physically" haben? Beispiele:

- Ich wechsle/tausche/konvertiere mein Geld von Dollar in Euro (um).
- Ich tausche Dollar gegen Euro.

Ich sehe keine Beispiele mit "tauschen" wie das, aber ich verstehe nicht, ob (1) ich die Bedeutung des Verbs falsch verstanden habe und dieser Satz falsch ist oder (2) es einfach nicht üblich ist.

Erfordert "konvertieren", dass eine Währung inländisch und die andere ausländisch ist? Zum Beispiel könnte ich nicht in Brasilien leben und Geld von Euro in Dollar konvertieren?

Es scheint mir, dass  "umrechnen" nur finanzielle geistige Umwandlungen ausdrückt, nicht physische. Man zieht einfach den entsprechenden Wert eines Betrags in der Währung B aus einem Betrag in der Währung A und dem Wechselkurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wer mal im Ausland unterwegs war kennt sicher den Begriff Wechselstube (oder Wechselkurse). In diesen kann man sein Geld gegen die Landeswährung wechseln. Oder tauschen? Oder konvertieren? Sehen wir es uns an.

Schauen wir mal was unser aller Liebling der Duden dazu sagt:

> [tauschen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tauschen) - jemandem eine Sache oder Person überlassen und dafür als Gegenleistung etwas, jemanden anderes von ihm erhalten
>
> [wechseln](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wechseln) - jemandem etwas zukommen lassen und von ihm etwas derselben Art erhalten / in eine andere Währung umtauschen
>
> [konvertieren](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/konvertieren) - (Wirtschaft) eine Währung gegen eine andere tauschen
>
> [umrechnen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/umrechnen) - ausrechnen, wie viel etwas in einer anderen Einheit ergibt

Hier sehen wir, dass tauschen und wechseln im Zusammenhang "to exchange money physically" synonym zueinander sind. Beides ist möglich. Durch etablierte Begriffe wie die oben genannte Wechselstube oder auch Wechselkurse würde ich allerdings wechseln bevorzugen.

Umrechnen fällt raus, da hier die nichts physisches passiert. Es ist reine Mathematik. Allerdings wird der Betrag den man erhält, anhand der aktuellen Wechselkurse, ausgerechnet, bzw der Originalbetrag in den Auszahlbetrag umgerechnet. Es ist also, wenn man will, ein Teil des ganzen Prozesses.

---

Bleibt also das konvertieren. Hier zitiere ich [diese Seite](https://www.bezahlen.de/lexikon/konvertierung_3264.html)

> Wird ein Betrag von einer Währung in eine andere überführt, so stellt dies eine Konvertierung dar.

[und](https://www.currencyfair.com/de/wie-es-funktioniert/wechseln-verarbeitungsdauer/)

> Wähle die Währung, die du an dein [...]-Konto (die Währung, aus der du konvertieren möchtest) und deine Überweisungswährung (die Währung, in die du umtauschst),um die relevanten Prozesszeiten und Gebühren anzuzeigen.

Für die Konvertierung ist es also unerheblich, ob man in die (oder aus der) Landeswährung konvertiert. Es sind nur zwei unterschiedliche Währungen nötig.

Da man den Begriff allerdings in erster Linie bei Währungsrechnern und im Bankingbereich findet sage ich jetzt, dass im "to exchange money physically"-Zusammenhang konvertieren keine Alternative ist.

Comment: Es wird Dich vielleicht überraschen, aber man muss dafür nicht im Ausland unterwegs sein - ein Flughafen oder Bahnhofsvorplatz genügt da aus, denn für Ausländer ist Deutschland Ausland. :)

Comment: @user: Das deutsche Ausland ist allerdings kleiner als z.B. das niederländische. <g>